# iOS OCUnit Deprecated cannot Convert to XCTest

Tags: ios, xcode, ocunit

Good day mates! I just want to ask if how can i fix this problem. I'm using xcode 5.1.1 with the device version 7.1.1, but this is working on xcode 5.0 and if the device is 7.0 below. but in this new updates im getting this problem.

[image]

I Tried to look for solution and i got something that you need to convert the OCUnit to XCTest, but when i tried to convert it by going to Edit>Refractor>Convert to XCTest...

I only got this.
[image]
Just a blank window without nothing to select. how can i fix this :( Please help.

Comment: What if you fix the unused variable error, or change unused variables from warnings to errors? Wondering if the build failure is keeping it from running correctly.

Comment: Yes i also tried it. but i think the problem is the OCUnit. because its working on lower version. And in the Latest version it said that its deprecated.